# NServiceBus requires explicit message registration in different environments

Tags: nservicebus

I am running windows 7 64 bit in all environemnts. Registering all messages implicitly by including my two assemblies works in development, but QA and Prod require explicit registrations else NService throws an exception at startup.
Has anyone encountered similar and do you have a solution?

The exception

```
Source:NServiceBus.Core System.InvalidOperationException - No destination could be found for message type
xyz.Application.Claims.Messaging.IGlassWorkflowEventMessage. Check the <MessageEndpointMapping> section of the configuration 
of this endpoint for an entry either for this specific message type or for its assembly.
Stack:   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.Subscribe(Type messageType, Predicate`1 condition)
at CEI.Application.Claims.GlassSubscriber.SubscriberEndpointStartup.Run() in c:\xyz\tfs\Claimslink\DEV\Bus\GlassSubscriber\Config\SubscriberEndpointStartup.cs:line 36
at NServiceBus.Host.Internal.ConfigManager.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Startup>b__0()
```

My config entries

```
<!--This works in my development environment-->
<MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="GlassSubscriber" ErrorQueue="GlassSubscriberError" NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="2"/>
<UnicastBusConfig>
<MessageEndpointMappings>

  <!--Just add assemblies, all messages recognized -->
  <add Messages="xyz.shared.impl" Endpoint="msgsvcpubinputqueue"/>
  <add Messages="xyz.Claims.impl" Endpoint="msgsvcpubinputqueue"/>
</MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>


 <!--QA and Production always require explicit message registrations??-->
 <MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="GlassSubscriber" ErrorQueue="GlassSubscriberError" NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="2"/>
 <UnicastBusConfig>
<MessageEndpointMappings>
  <add Messages="xyz.shared.impl" Endpoint="msgsvcpubinputqueue"/>
  <add Messages="xyz.Claims.impl" Endpoint="msgsvcpubinputqueue"/>

  <!--We have dozens of messages, explicitly registering for each subscriber is a pain-->

  <add Messages="xyz.Application.Claims.Messaging.IGlassWorkflowEventMessage, xyz.Claims.impl" Endpoint="msgsvcpubinputqueue"/>
  <add Messages="xyz.Application.Claims.Messaging.GlassWorkflowEventMessage, xyz.Claims.impl" Endpoint="msgsvcpubinputqueue"/>
</MessageEndpointMappings>
 </UnicastBusConfig>
```

Comment: What happens when you add "@machineName" where machineName is the machine in which the NSB process is running after "msgsvcpubinputqueue"?

Comment: All 3 environments Dev, QA, Prod, the publisher is running on the same machine as the subscribers.

Comment: Huh, that is odd.  Can't be permissions if the explicit ones work.

Comment: Which version of NServiceBus are you using?

Comment: 2.6.0.1511  We've been using Nbus for about 2 years and we didn't have this problem before. I can't isolate the precise time it occurred but it may be release related. I should note that older subscribers that were not uninstalled and simply upgraded to the latest NServiceBus.Host.exe do NOT require explicit registrations. The problem only occurs on new subscribers we've tested in Dev (without explicit registrations) then installed in QA and Prod. In all cases Qa and Prod work by editting the config and adding explicit message registration, no code changes.

Comment: I should note we have tried both Debug and Release assemmblies with no effect.